# How do you set up a peer-to-peer connection for an online game built for the web?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multiplayer, webrtc, socket.io

I've looked into different kinds of technologies built for the web for the past few months and I've been thinking about making a game for the web. The problem is I'm not familiar of how to use these technologies for the specific purpose of connecting two players to a game. The game at this state is at beta, but I've been stuck with the part in which two players are able to connect each other through URL exchanges like the game [Cube Slam](https://www.cubeslam.com/tech) created by Google.
Cube slam uses a method in which the original player gives their friend or opponent a link and the game connects both players to start a match, but I've looked into the channel api, but with no luck of finding any good tutorials other than Google's documentation on the api. I would assume I'd have to use Google's app engine.

My plan is this, I want to user to first place their name into a input form after doing so they will get a link to share with the other player and the game will start. The problem is I'm not quite sure how to tackle this very part. I have a few question that I would like to get answered. Thank you in advance.

1. How  did Google make the Cube slam gameplay so that when you play with the opponent the game starts without loading a new page? Is this done through Ajax?

2.how do I setup a connection with two players?

1. Would it be easier to use Googles method of sending the opponent a URL? Or would it be easier to type your name, click play and find a random user, and if so how would this be done?
2. I've looked at a couple of methods of incorporating online interactions with players such as:

NodeJS
PeerJS
Socket.IO
WebRTC
Google's Channel API

Which of these are more suitable on easier for my situation?

1. Can anyone give me any sample codes, tutorials, methods, or ideologies in which I can accomplish this task. I have a great game idea, I'm just stuck with this very aspect sadly.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cube Slam uses the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/) for messaging/signaling, along with Ajax. The [HTML5 Rocks WebRTC article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-simple) describes how this is done for the [apprtc.appspot.com](http://apprtc.appspot.com) video chat app.

Another alternative, as you suggest, is to use something like Socket.IO. I built a codelab that gives step by step instructions on how to do that: [bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab](http://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab).

Comment: Thank you for showing me these articles. This was very helpful. I'll take a look at the codelab, but I'm confused with one part. When you say "Open the document in multiple windows or tab." I'd assume users are going into the window and then seeing multiple people, but my game requires it to have only two people per game. How do I manage that with Socket.io? I know your codelab was meant to give me an idea of how to approach my problem, but I'm just looking to connect two players at a time.

Comment: I'll study these methods and try to come up with a solution. I'm not quite familiar with Nodejs, Socket.io, or WebRTC at the moment. Luckily that link you gave me from HTML5 rocks provided lots of references. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Somnibyte: by 'multiple', I really meant two :). Will correct. The codelab example is only designed for two users.

Comment: Sam, thank you for your help. I was able to make a game using Nodejs, SocketIO, and Express. Here it is: http://www.wordmelee.com Hope you like it.